# dart create generic functions take and return a class type

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm creating a generic API that should work with any class follow some rules.

For example, each class work with my API should have the 2 following function:

```
static <ClassType> fromDocument(Map<String, String> data) { return ClassType(...)};
Map<String, String> toDocument() { return {...}};
```

in the other hand, I want to create a generic function that should upload and get document from server

```
void uploadModel(dynamic anyClassInstance) {
  server.upload(anyClassInstance.toDocument());
}

<classType> getModel(String id, ClassType) {
  Map<String, String> data = server.getData(id);
  return ClassType.fromDocument(data);
}
```

How can I achieve this functionality, where those function should work with any class type I have. I tried using generics but without success.

Comment: You cannot use a generic parameter to access static methods.  The closest you can get is a hand-rolled switch that selects explicit static methods based on type.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz thanks for your reply, but this will break the getModel function, at the end I'm interested in returning a new instance of that class, I can make return value dynamic and do casting later, but how can I get that classType to know which from document to call ?

Comment: You need to pass a callback that constructs an instance of the class you want or your function needs to work with a fixed set of classes.

Comment: I think I might go with the callback, a wrapper of the abstract function

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are trying to do, is most closely to conform to Liskov substitution principle.

look at the following code:

```
abstract class DocumentType{
  
  DocumentType fromDocument(Map<String, String> data);
  Map<String, String> toDocument(); 
}

class MyDocy1 extends DocumentType{
  
  DocumentType fromDocument(Map<String, String> data){
    
    return MyDocy1();
    
  }
  
  Map<String, String> toDocument(){
    
    return {'documentName' : 'MyDocy1'};
  }
  
}

class MyDocy2 extends DocumentType{
  
  DocumentType fromDocument(Map<String, String> data){
    
    return MyDocy2();
    
  }
  
  Map<String, String> toDocument(){
    
    return {'documentName' : 'MyDocy2'};
  }
  
}
```

only, extend or implement that abstract class and override its abstract methods to be from `DocumentType`.

after that

```
void main() {
  
  uploadModel(MyDocy2());
  getModel(MyDocy1());
  
 
}
void uploadModel(DocumentType doc) {
  
 print(doc.toDocument());
  
}

void getModel(DocumentType dt) {
  
 print(dt.runtimeType);
}
```

**output**

> {documentName: MyDocy2}
>
> MyDocy1

you can do whatever you want on both methods with **predefined knowing of the object type** (`MyDocy1` or `MyDocy2`).

at last, i tried to be concise, think that way is the optimal way to deal with your needs, not generics.

but note: abstract methods are not allowed to be static methods.(logically), for more info try to search about Liskov Substitution principle.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Actually it does help, in one hand I need an abstract method to return new instance, what you suggested required an instance of the class to be passed to activate from document, but I can think of creating empty constructor for this case, or as suggested in comment to use callback, THANKS!!!